# How to guess the basis

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be a silly question, but still I'm asking you. Suppose you are given a vector space. How do you guess the basis? I think is this not always easy to guess the maximal linearly independent set which spans the vector space! Give me some way how to think about a basis in an arbitrary vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space. I will address the case that $V$ is finite dimensional.

If $V = \{0\}$, then $\emptyset$ is the only basis for $V$, so you're done. If $V \neq \emptyset$, then there is $v_1 \in V$, $v_1 \neq 0$. Note that $\{v_1\}$ is a linearly independent set and $\operatorname{span}\{v_1\} \subseteq V$. If $\operatorname{span}\{v_1\} = V$, then $\{v_1\}$ is a basis for $V$. If $\operatorname{span}\{v_1\} \neq V$, then there is $v_2 \in V$, such that $v_2 \notin \operatorname{span}\{v_1\}$, then $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is linearly independent and $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2\} \subseteq V$. Because $V$ is finite dimensional, we eventually obtain a linearly independent set $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ with $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \dots, v_k\} = V$.

The point is that it is fairly easy to construct a basis for a finite dimensional vector space, and there are lots of different bases to choose from.

Comment: Its ok!
but suppose you are given a subspace of the space of matrices. Then how to find its basis?

Comment: Normally, you do this, by looking for "nice" simple elements of the vector space which span the space. For e.g. the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$,the obvious choice is $(1, x, \dots, x^n)$. In your case, we would have to see the subspace explicitely. For the case of all symmetric matrices (for example), you would e.g. take all matrices that have a single $1$ in the upper right half of the matrix (including the diagonal) and which are symmetric.